# How can I get a multiline custom title on android?

Tags: android, layout, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am working on a xamarin project (has no relevance here as far as I can tell - the android layout properties are the same)

I am using `Window.SetFeatureInt (WindowFeatures.CustomTitle, ...)` to set the title (2 "columns".  I wish to make two rows of text though for my title.  Is this possible?   I have not had much success.  I have an upper left, upper right and lower left and lower right TextViews to set.

My previous attempts have ended up with the TextViews overwriting each other.

Comment: Another user suggested to "Use popupwindow http://virenandroid.blogspot.com/2011/11/custom-popupwindow-android.html "  - but the answer was deleted after a critical comment was put up about posting just links.  The link was helpful actually.

Answer (score 0):

> Here I am designing a XML file with an image, text for title & button. This is the XML file. U can use it however you want, for a complete application or perticular activity.
>   In case of activity add this activity's theme tag. For multi line just use text view in side the below linear layout, set it as multline true.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="35dip"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

   <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/header"
          android:background="@drawable/icon"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Custom Window Text"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:textStyle="bold"/>

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Button" />
```

```
  Create a theme in Custom_theme.xml,

  <resources>
   <style name="CustomWindowTitleBarBG">
          <item name="android:background">#323331</item>
  </style>

  <style name="TitleBarTheme" parent="android:Theme">
         <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">      @style/CustomWindowTitleBarBG</item>
  </style>
```

Modify the AndroidManifest.xml file as follows for applying custom theme

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/TitleBarTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".CustomWindowTitle"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Now in main java file `add “requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE)” &
“getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title)”`

This is the code snippet for CustomWindowTitle.java

```
package com.example.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class CustomWindowTitle extends Activity
  {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,    R.layout.window_title);
    }
 }
```